# Clicking 3 Buttons At Once Every Two Seconds Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, click

All the buttons have the same class.

I want to create a JavaScript which clicks on 3 buttons at once every 2 seconds.

I've found this script:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('vote-icon');

for (var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++)  
       
buttons[i].click();
```

... but it clicks on all the buttons that are found on the page.

What can I do to make this script click 3 buttons at once, every 2 seconds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use **setInterval**.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('vote-icon');
console.log(buttons);

  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)  {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
      console.log("button clicked");
    })
  }   


setInterval(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)  {
    buttons[i].click();
  }    

},2000)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button class="vote-icon">1</button>
    <button class="vote-icon">2</button>
    <button class="vote-icon">3</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. On that page, there are over 20 buttons displayed. Can you adjust this JavaScript to click only on 3 buttons at once?

Comment: @OvidiuDrobotă Depending on your scenario you can either add another specific class to them to select them alone or you can use indexes. Like instead of "i < buttons.length" you can put "i < 3" so it will go until the 3rd button (first 3 buttons).

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you help me adjust this script to skip already clicked buttons and go click on the next ones? Let's say there are 50 buttons to click. When I run the script, I want the script to click the first 3 buttons and then to go for the next 3 ones and so forth, but to always skip the clicked ones because I don't want the clicked buttons to be unclicked. Let me know if something's not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can define a variable "var begin = 0;" out of interval and run click like this "buttons[i+begin].click()" and after that you can do a "i +=3;" so that on next interval it will go for next 3 buttons

Comment: You're a great person. Thank you for helping me. I did everything right, excepting "i += 3". Could you edit the code for me so I can understand it better? Thanks.

Comment: @Ovidiu Drobotă At this point you want me to write your entire project yet not even accepting my answer. Feels like i'm getting trolled

Comment: I'm not trolling you man. I'm just asking for advice because I'm not a programmer yet and that's why I need help.

Comment: @OvidiuDrobotă: please don't ask others to write code for you as that is not the purpose of this site. If you're not a programmer then it's time to become one and try to re-write your code based on these recommendations.